How to create a list inside an object by userID in Kotlin for Firebase Realtime Database?
I'm working on an Android project using Kotlin and Firebase Realtime Database. I want to structure my data in such a way that each user has a list of conversations with other users. Each conversation contains the latest message exchanged between the two users.
Here's an example of the data structure I want to achieve:
{
  "403": {
    "conversations": [
      {
        "id": "conversation_403_407_2024-05-08_18:31:38",
        "latest_message": {
          "date": "2024-05-08 18:32:43",
          "isRead": false,
          "message": "Jhbhjbhbckskjcbdsljkcnjldsvljdsjlcdskjcvbjkdsbvkjdvjlwvjl"
        },
        "name": "djFbtu315",
        "otherUserId": 407
      }
    ]
  },
  "407": {
    "conversations": [
      {
        "id": "conversation_403_407_2024-05-08_18:31:38",
        "latest_message": {
          "date": "2024-05-08 18:32:43",
          "isRead": true,
          "message": "Jhbhjbhbckskjcbdsljkcnjldsvljdsjlcdskjcvbjkdsbvkjdvjlwvjl"
        },
        "name": "my basic profile",
        "otherUserId": 403
      },
      {
        "id": "conversation_408_407_2024-05-08_19:31:02",
        "latest_message": {
          "date": "2024-05-08 19:31:02",
          "isRead": true,
          "message": "22"
        },
        "name": "Muhammad",
        "otherUserId": 408
      },
      {
        "id": "conversation_507_407_2024-05-08_19:38:47",
        "latest_message": {
          "date": "2024-05-08 19:39:15",
          "isRead": true,
          "message": "22"
        },
        "name": "Manuel Crandall",
        "otherUserId": 507
      }
    ]
  }
}

I'm struggling to implement this structure in Kotlin when adding or updating conversations. Here's my current code:
fun addUser(userId: String) {
    val usersReference: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    val userDetails = intent.getParcelableExtra<ConnectionDetailDTO>("USER_DETAILS")
    otherUserId = userDetails?.id!!
    currentUserId = currentUser?.id!!

    usersReference.child(userId).get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User already exists with ID: $userId")
        } else {
            val user = hashMapOf(
                "conversations" to listOf<Conversations>()
            )
            usersReference.child(userId).setValue(true)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User created with ID: $userId")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error creating user: $e")
                }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Error checking user existence: $e")
    }
}

My table name is "Users"
I need help modifying this code to achieve the desired data structure. Specifically, I'm unsure how to handle adding conversations to the list inside the user object, and how to update the latest message if the conversation already exists.
This is the data class:
data class Conversations(
    val id: String = "",
    val latest_message: LatestMessage = LatestMessage(),
    val name: String = "",
    val otherUserId: Int = 0 
) {
    data class LatestMessage(
        val date: String = "",
        val isRead: Boolean = false,
        val message: String = "" 
    )
}
data class ChatUser(
    val id: Long = 0, // User ID
    val conversations: List<Conversations> = emptyList()
)


Your conversations nodes is modeled as a List/array, which is a common (and well documented) anti-pattern when using the Firebase Realtime Database. I recommend reading Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase, and the documentation on how to read and write data in lists.
Once you've switched to this recommended structure, you can add a new conversation by calling push(), and update any existing conversation based on knowing its push key. If you're having trouble at that point, please post a new question that shows what you tried.
